# Programmatically created UIViewController loading an Interface builder view.xib file

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xib

How to load an interface builder created view from a programmatically created UIViewController? I'm using Objective-C.

I was able to start with a reference project that did not use the interface builder, so I have no storyboard. I have successfully loaded views programmatically, but would like to be able to load some that were interface builder created.

More detail:  I have 2 view controllers A and B.  I'm currently in A.  I click a button and in that button handler I load Viewcontroller B like this:

```
self.viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES]
```

I manually created a ViewB with a .m and .h.  If I use an initWithFrame wherein i define a bunch of controls and lay them out programmatically, I can successfully call it as described above.

I add a new file to the project, which is a UIView which brings it up in the builder.  Drop a TableView onto the view, and now I just want to see this load.
I named the xib ViewB.xib, I set the Class to ViewB like the pic below shows (In answer 1)

Comment: have you tried calling the instance method : - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle?

Comment: Yes, unless I was doing something wrong with the nibName. How do i set and know excactly what the nibName is?

Comment: The Nib name is whatever you named it when creating it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to load a view from a .xib use this:

First make a nib for the view in interface builder, and be sure to set its custom class to your view's class, see the picture:

[image]

and then load it in your code like this:

```
MyCustomNibView *myView;
NSArray *topLevelItems = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomNibView" owner:nil options:nil];

for (id view in topLevelItems) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[MyCustomNibView class]]) {
       myView = (MyCustomNibView *)view;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the code go in the example above?  Is this in a corresponding .m and .h file for the 'MyCustomNibView', or are those not required.  Is this directly in the view controller?  If in the view controller how does it recognize the 'MyCustomNibView' without a .h reference? I presume that in the picture above the Class name needs to be 'MyCustomNibView' (for this example).

Comment: @Kazern You need a 'MyCustomNibView.h', 'MyCustomNibView.m' and a 'MyCustomNibView.xib' which define your view and its members. In the picture, as you guessed, the class should be 'MyCustomNibView'. Finally you import the .h in your view controller and use the code above whenever you want to load your view. It can be in 'viewDidLoad' or on some button tap or ...etc. After you get the view using the code above you just add it to your view hierarchy.